# return function within to create closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I watched a tutorial of functional programming. The author introduced something like this:

[image]

Where the exercise sounds like this

1. Define `foo(..)` so that it produces a function which remembers only the first two arguments that were passed to `foo(..)`, and always adds them together.

I came out with this

```
function foo(x,y){
return x,7;
}
foo(3,4);
```

What's wrong with my solution? I'm confused.

Comment: Your `foo` doesn't return a function, and it doesn't make addition with the arguments.

Comment: The problem with your solution is simple, and can be demonstrated by this XKCD comic: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: If the tutorial doesn't explain what it's doing maybe it's best to find a better tutorial.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want an explanation of how the example in the tutorial works? Or do you want to know, why your implementation doesn't work? Or do you want an alternative way to do what was requested? Or do you want something else?

Comment: alert(foo(1,2)()) should alert 3 not alert(foo(1,2))

Answer (score 0):

> A closure is an inner function that has access to the outer
>   (enclosing) function's variables—scope chain. The closure has three
>   scope chains: it has access to its own scope (variables defined
>   between its curly brackets), it has access to the outer function's
>   variables, and it has access to the global variables.

So

```
function foo(x,y) {
   return function() {
      return x + y;
   }
}
```

`var x = foo(3,4);`

Here foo function is called with 3 & 4 as argument, and the return value of foo is also a function(closuer).

As said inner function has access to the outer scope variable, here the function returned by foo has access to the foo's context i.e inner function can access variable's x & y

so calling x() will return 7.

Comment: And a closure is more an object, that contains a function and its environment. This is used by js to keep the scope

Comment: I know it will return 7, I'm asking why. I can just do return x + y without extra function in the function of `foo`

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(x1,y1) {
    var x2 = x1, y1 = y2;
    return function() {
        return x2 + y2;
    }
}

var x = foo(3,4);
```

At this point `x` is

```
function() {
    return 3 + 4;
}
```

Hope this explains what you are missing

Comment: I know it will return 7, I'm asking why. I can just do return x + y without extra function in the function of `foo`.

Comment: @NingSia you are return a function that will always have those variables set. So when you call `x()` it will always give you `7`. Of course in this example it might not make much sense for you but the example is just showing the concept. For instance you could use a multiplier function where the multiplier is set initially and then just call the returned function

Answer (score 0):

Jaguwalapratik already answered your question, but i think youre not quite understanding the closure, thats why i write this as an explanation for the closure.

Lets imagine your an Interpreter that has to execute this code step by step:

```
a=foo(3,4);
```

Ok im searching foo and pass 3,4 to it and store its return value to x.
Im creating a new scope for foo, and set 3 and 4.

```
return function(){return x+y}
```

Ah ok i store it in a. The execution of foo has finished, lets delete x,y as i dont need them anymore.

```
a();
```

Ok a returns x+y but i dont now what x and y is. Ive delted them. Thats the problem the js engineers faced, and they had a brilliant idea: **closures**.

```
A Closure stores not only the function to a variable, but also its environment, to solve the scope loosing problem.
```

Ok lets do it again with closures:

```
a=foo(3,4);
```

Oh it returns a function, thats not good. So may i loose the scope, so i need to remember all the variables and functions that were declared inside of foo:

```
a=function(){return x+y;}
a.environment={
  x:3;
  y:4;
}
```

Now i can delete foos scope, all the necessary data is inside the closure.

```
a();
```

No problem! x and y are inside of the closure. Problem solved.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I know it will return 7, I'm asking why. I can just do return x + y without extra function in the function of foo.

Comment: @Ning Sia: but that wouldnt create a closure, and you need closures in object oriented programming, programming apis etc.

Answer (score -1):

You should write the addition of two parameters. It should look something like that.

```
function foo(x,y) {
    return function() {
        return x + y;
    }
}

var x = foo(3,4);
```

Comment: Why are you rewrite the solution in the image? I need explanation, not code.

Comment: In your code you use not x,7 but x+y. You should return the result of your function, but not coma separated values.